# Add a Label to the Polygon in Cesium

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cesiumjs, czml

How can I add a label to the entity (ex. Polygon) at the specify location:

This is how I tried to do it: (entity.polygon = true)

```
static addLabel(entity) {
        entity.myLabel = new Cesium.LabelGraphics({
            position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 39.9522222),
            label : {
                text : 'Philadelphia',
                font : '24px Helvetica',
                fillColor : Cesium.Color.SKYBLUE,
                outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLACK,
                outlineWidth : 2,
            }
        })
    }
```

There is no error, but it doesn't show up on the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "label" is an object of the entity so try this:

```
entity.label= new Cesium.LabelGraphics({
            position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 39.9522222),
            text : 'Philadelphia',
            font : '24px Helvetica',
            fillColor : Cesium.Color.SKYBLUE,
            outlineColor : Cesium.Color.BLACK,
            outlineWidth : 2,


        })
```

to hide it use

> enity.label.show=false;